# Magento Discount setup

Tags: magento-1.9, discount, coupon-codes

Now I need,

**Product A having maximum discount 3% discount.** 
(please tell me how can i set the maximum discount in percentage)

At the same the Customer Group members having **couponcode** **for 5%**

Now the Product **should be discount upto 3%** **not above 3%**
**Even They Entered the Coupon code for 5%**.

Comment: one option is,  assume : `product A price = 100` , you guys want to give `3 %` so final price will be `97`.... instead of that, keep product price = `103 or 104`, so that final price will be again `97` so if discount is 5% also , final price will be same.....

Comment: is there any way to reach that, except changing the product price.??

Comment: don't you think customers will  get shock when you tell them `this coupon code will give you 5 % & when they applied , they will get only 3 % once they applied` ?

Comment: In Our Criteria, We Displaying  "This Product discount upto 3% not applicable for 5%, try the coupon code for other prouduct."

Comment: got it, seems you don't want to give multiple coupon code also for 3% & 5 % , in this case sorry i have no idea.....

Comment: Yeah of course. The product default having 3% of discount. when the customer was "Retailer". we give the coupon code for retailer for 5% to 10%(depend upon certain process).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/46237/discussion-between-crock-and-baby-in-magento).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done this, Editing the getPrice() Functions in below path.

Finally i have customized the price caluclation.

1. app\code\core\Mage\Sales\Model\Quote\Item\Abstract.php - function getPrice()
2. app\code\core\Mage\Tax\Helper\Data.php - function getPrice($product, $price.....)
3. app\code\core\Mage\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\Price.php - function getPrice($product)